# How to access Google Calendar application event data in another Android application

Tags: android, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am developing one application in which i need to fetch all the event's data which i have added in **Google Calendar** application from my phone. We can add events offline even while internet is not connected in that application. So that kind of events which is offline added, i also need to access those events also in my application. In essence, I need to access Google calendar application events to my android application without using API.
So my question is **Can we access events from Google Calendar application to another application or else I need to use CalendarAPI ?**

Comment: Take a look at Calendar Provider: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Comment: Using Calendar Provider may i get the event data from Google Calendar application installed on my phone ? @luc

Comment: Yes, take a look at the Events table.

Answer (score 1):

**Based on luc answer.**

The Calendar Provider is a repository for a user's calendar events. The Calendar Provider API allows you to perform query, insert, update, and delete operations on calendars, events, attendees, reminders, and so on.

The Calender Provider API can be used by applications and sync adapters. The rules vary depending on what type of program is making the calls. This document focuses primarily on using the Calendar Provider API as an application.

To directly insert, modify, and read events from the Calendar Provider, you need the appropriate permissions. However, if you're not building a full-fledged calendar application or sync adapter, requesting these permissions isn't necessary. You can instead use intents supported by Android's Calendar application to hand off read and write operations to that application. When you use the intents, your application sends users to the Calendar application to perform the desired operation in a pre-filled form. After they're done, they're returned to your application. By designing your application to perform common operations through the Calendar, you provide users with a consistent, robust user interface. This is the recommended approach.

I don't know if it can help you, but another way is by using Google Calendar to your other application, then you can use the [Google Account](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en)
With some calendar applications, you can sync your calendar using your Google Account. This means you can add and edit events from either Google Calendar or your other application.

1. Open your other calendar application.
2. Look for an option to add another account. This might be in Settings or Preferences.
3. Sign in with your Google account. If you use 2-step verification with your account, you'll have to enter an app password.
4. Follow the steps to add your Google Account.

Comment: Your information is much useful but can u provide any sample code for that which consist the access of google calendar data from its app to my own app ? @KENdi